# Trying to make the program give me the longest word in a sentence

Tags: python

The question is, when i have a sentence that contains two words with the same amount of letters, how do i make the program give me the first longest word when reading instead of both?

```
import sys 

inputsentence = input("Enter a sentence and I will find the longest word: ").split()
longestwords = []
for word in inputsentence:
    if len(word) == len(max(inputsentence, key=len)):
        longestwords.append(word)

print ("the longest word in the sentence is:",longestwords)
```

example: the quick brown fox...right now the program gives me "quick" and "brown", how do tweak my code to just give me "quick" since its the first longest word?

Comment: try to use break after longestwords.append(word)  line

Answer (score 8):

I would get rid of the for-loop altogether and just do this:

```
>>> mystr = input("Enter a sentence and I will find the longest word: ")
Enter a sentence and I will find the longest word: The quick brown fox
>>> longest = max(mystr.split(), key=len)
>>> print("the longest word in the sentence is:", longest)
the longest word in the sentence is: quick
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just print the first one in the list:

```
print ("the longest word in the sentence is:",longestwords[0])
```

There are likely better ways to do this, but this requires the least modification to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
longest_word = None

for word in inputsentence:
    if len(word) == len(max(inputsentence, key=len)):
        longest_word = word

print ("the longest word in the sentence is:",longest_word)
```

Answer (score 0):

More pythonic way

```
import sys 

inputsentence = input("Enter a sentence and I will find the longest word: ").split()
# use function len() as criteria to sort
inputsentence.sort(key=len)
# -1 is last item on list
print ("the longest word in the sentence is:", sentence[-1])
```